# jQuery val() returns empty string for number input fields when they have dot or comma in them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I *think* it depends on what number settings you have in your OS. But: for me, I can enter dots `.` into input fields. Which for my application, is undesired. I want to disable decimals, and everything that is not a number

As a bonus, jquery does not detect dots in number fields

https://codepen.io/jossnaz/pen/dLMmoQ

looks like this:

[image]

HTML:

```
Please type into the first input box some dots . then click out of the input box to trigger the change event <br> <br>
<input type="number" name="firstInput" value="....">
<input type="number" name="second" value="5">

<pre class="result"></pre>
```

Javascript:

```
$('input').on('change', function(){

  $('.result').html(
  'First input val: ' + $('input').first().val() + "<br/>" + "Second input val: "
  +   $('input').last().val()
);
})
```

Comment: jQuery only returns what the browser tells it is there. What is the question here?

Comment: @charlietfl well, somebody was somehow able to submit a `,` in an input number only field. The question is, how can I make sure that doesn't happen?

Comment: Remember that different locales have different number formats. Up to you to validate server side no matter what you do client side also. User input can never be trusted and can completely bypass your form even

Comment: Well just take care `type=number` does allow: `e`,`.`,`-`,`+`.

Comment: @Mukyuu that can easily be changed though. Simple to remove the type attribute in dev tools and put anything in there. It's only a convenience...not a sure thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pattern` attribute of input tag

```
^\d+$
```

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - Matches any digit one or more time
- `$` - End of string

```html
 <br> <br>
 <form>
<input type="number" name="firstInput" value="" pattern="^\d+$">
<button type='submit'>Submit</button>

<pre class="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Try to change the above html input element type="number" --> type="text"
<input type="number" name="firstInput" value="....">
<input type="text" name="firstInput" value="....">
```